# Does python's pip support http authentication?

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

As the title says, does pip support http authentication, like easy_install does?

If not, are there any (better) alternatives to running a private package repository?  I see pip can access source repositories (git,svn etc.), but can version requirements be used with this?

Comment: [It should](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/51).

Answer (score 6):

For people still searching for an answer you can use the following syntax:

```
pip install -r https://user:pass@domain.com/path/requirements.txt
```

An also if you require to validate their certificate use:

```
pip install --cert host.pem -r https://user:pass@domain.com/path/requirements.txt
```

This is working on:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

To upgrade your pip do:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: There's no way to do this without using plaintext passwords?

Comment: I just found this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/5952 .  It appears that you can use keyring with pip, but I can't find any usage documentation.  It also appears that pip supports `.netrc` files in `~` and `.`, but again, no usage documentation.

Answer (score 3):

pip [uses](http://oss.openplans.org/pip/browser/pip/trunk/pip.py) urllib2.urlopen() to fetch files. urllib2.urlopen() supports HTTP authentication, but pip doesn't appear to install the HTTPBasicAuthHandler when it builds its opener. Adding such support would be trivial; you could either parse the URL for user:password or accept the same information as command line parameters. [feedparser](http://feedparser.org/docs/http-authentication.html) supports both methods by [subclassing](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/source/browse/trunk/feedparser/feedparser.py) urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler.

Answer (score 2):

Currently simply pip does not support authentication.

But [the main author of pip thinks that feature is desirable](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/msg/7aff34d86c595f84) so probably it will appear in the medium future. There is also [an item in the PIP trac](http://projects.openplans.org/pip/ticket/30) containing a patch to enable http auth.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, it's currently being worked on in the [`http_auth_index`](http://github.com/brosner/pip/tree/http_auth_index) branch which will allow the use of basic auth for custom indexes.